# Problems with removing elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, fadeout

I am attempting to remove an object from a page with jQuery. I also want to animate the removal. The goal is to make the element fadeOut(), wait a second, then remove(). But it seems to refuse to wait to remove the element, even when I use it in a setTimeout() function. How can I make an element fadeOut(), and then remove() it?

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
    setTimeout(function() { $(this).remove();}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your timeout function, `this` isn't what you think it is - it's actually the global `window` object.

In any event (no pun intended) you should use a "completion callback":

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Never, ever, mix `setTimeout` and the animation queue.  It's fine to *interleave* the two, i.e having a completion callback start a timer, or having a timer starting an animation, but it's never OK to assume that you can start both a 1000ms animation and a 1000ms timer and have them complete at the same time.

**EDIT** fixed code - no need for `self` in a completion callback, I was still thinking about `setTimeout` and `this` when I wrote that!

Comment: in a `setTimeout` handler it's the global `window` object, AFAIK.

Comment: sorry, what is AFAIK, i'm interpreting it as "a fake".

Answer (score 8):

Read manual carefully:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

The fadeOut() method has a callback that is invoked after the fadeOut completes. To use it:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
});
```

There should be no reason to wait one second after the fadeOut completes, before removing the element, because the element will be invisible when it is removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove()});
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AZDsT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the callback of fadeout?

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, maybe it helps:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    (function(that) {
        that.fadeOut();
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.remove();
        }, 1000);
    })($(this));
});
```

Comment: that = $(this);   it serves to store variable $(this), and you can use 'that' later in setTimeout